# Why does it go into a new line instead of continuing the uniformity?

Tags: html, css

So, I'm a newbie when it comes to HTML/CSS. So I downloaded a bootstrapped template and began working on it for my company (small). So far, I've completed everything but one section. I'm not sure how to convey this problem, so I'll simply demonstrate it to you.[problem shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJoV2.png)

```js
var i = 0;

function solar() {
  if (!i) {
    document.getElementById("more5").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("dots5").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("solar").innerHTML = "Read Less"
    i = 1;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("more5").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("dots5").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("solar").innerHTML = "Read More";
    i = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 ">
    <div class="box ">
      <div class="img-box">
        <img src="images/solar.png" alt="solar">
      </div>
      <div class="detail-box">
        <h5>
          Solar Panel Systems
        </h5>
        <p>
          Do you need something that isn't on the website? Do you need to to consult someone on<span id="dots5">...</span><span id="more5" style="display: none;"> something that has been bothering you with your devices, cameras, phones, alarms, solar panels? Do you need advice? Contact Us! IT'S FREE!!!</span>
        </p>
        <button type="button" id="solar" onclick="solar()">Read More</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the container with flex,

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-start flex-row flex-wrap">
...
</div>
```

Doc: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

Comment: sure I can but which one? do you want the snippet of the html code?


        </div>